# Create hashmap for JSON in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, hashmap

Is it possible to generate hashmap for JSON object in javascript/jquery? I've complex and big JSON object. I've to loop through it to filter data based on timings.

What is will be best and optimum approach to get data from JSON/hash map?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your JSON object and what you're trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers contain a native JSON object with a [JSON.parse(JSONstring)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method for just this. jQuery provides [$.getJSON(JSONstring)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to return an object from a JSON string in environments that don't natively provide the JSON object.

From there on, getting a useful hashmap depends on the structure of your JSON object. [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) (and its more performant offshoot, [LoDash](http://lodash.com)) contains a lot of useful methods (such as [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)) which can help parse, manipulate and retrieve useful data from large objects.